# race condition with NServicebus and service implementation

Tags: service, nservicebus, race-condition, saga

I have a saga-service ProcessCatalog that has the responsability on product
catalog publishing process.

A client application send to it a PublishCatalog message; each message contains
catalogid and the items list.

I've choose catalogid as SagaId.

ProcessCatalog service is a long running business process that arrange in proper
order other business service.

I need ProcessCatalog keep in mind the currently catalog items composition to
drive publishing process.

What happens whether the same user hit a first time on UI button to send the
PublishCatalog(catalogId=1, Itemlist={A,B,C} ) and then change catalog
composition (itemList ={A,D,E}) and so click another time on UI button to send
another PublishCatalog for the same CatalogId ?

If my ProcessCatalog endpoint is configured with one workerthread all works
fine (I think). But what happens if workthread is greater then 1 and the 2
messages are processed in concurrency ? What happens if the 2nd thread complete
execution before the 1st thread ?

I ask me if this is a business design bug or a normal technical problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Saga is managing state, the two messages should correlate to the same Saga.  In your Saga you will have to deal with each message and resolve any conflicts.  The business rules will have to define what happens if the catalog is changed while the publishing of the catalog is in process.

It may be the case that the Saga is allowed to complete and is followed by another Saga to modify the catalog.  Typically with product catalogs the consumer only cares about what is current and would be able to absorb changes after the initial publish.  If there is a ton of work to get something published, then you may want to cancel the Saga and restart it.  If this is the case then maybe the UI needs to turn more into a modeling tool where the user can play with the catalog and then commit when they are completely satisfied.

Comment: Hi Adam, from a business perspective you are right and I understood your point of view.
But, my doubt is relative to race condition scenario.
What happens if workthread is greater then 1 and the 2 messages are processed in concurrency ? What happens if the 2nd thread complete execution before the 1st thread ?
I should lock the saga row relative to the catalog id ?

Comment: I don't think you have a concurrency issue, but if you did, would be a lock on the row and then a first level retry will occur and it will be first come first serve.